# How to concatenate different date variables from within one column

Tags: excel, date, concatenation

I'm trying to work out a way to concatenate some data with dates where the dates are given in a variety of ways such as "mmm yyyy" or "yyyy". Example data formatted with columns A and B with General while Column C Customer is formatted with Custom mmm-yyyy or Custom 0000:

Example Data:

`({'Concatenate': ['=CONCATENATE(B2," - ",C2)'],  'Title': ['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Epsilon','Zeta','Eta','Theta'],  'Date': ['Jul-1995','1994','Mar-1996','Apr-1990','1996','Jun-1996','Jul-1997','Aug-1999']})`

When I concatenate the data using =CONCATENATE(B2," - ",C2) in A2 and drag the formula down Column A, I get:

`({'Concatenate': ['Alpha - 38441','Beta - 1994','Gamma - 35125','Delta - 32964','Epsilon - 1996','Zeta - 35217','Eta - 35612','Theta - 36373'],  'Title': ['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Epsilon','Zeta','Eta','Theta'],  'Date': ['Jul-1995','1994','Mar-1996','Apr-1990','1996','Jun-1996','Jul-1997','Aug-1999']})`

If I change the formula to =CONCATENATE(B2," - ",TEXT(C2,"MMM YYYY")), I get:

`({'Concatenate': ['Alpha - Jul 1995','Beta - 1905','Gamma - Mar 1996','Delta - Apr 1990','Epsilon - Jun 1905','Zeta - Jun 1996','Eta - Jul 1997','Theta - Aug 1999'],  'Title': ['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Epsilon','Zeta','Eta','Theta'],  'Date': ['Jul-1995','1994','Mar-1996','Apr-1990','1996','Jun-1996','Jul-1997','Aug-1999']})`

What I want is to concatenate and get the following:

`({'Concatenate': ['Alpha - Jul 1995','Beta - 1994','Gamma - Mar 1996','Delta - Apr 1990','Epsilon - 1999','Zeta - Jun 1996','Eta - Jul 1997','Theta - Aug 1999'],  'Title': ['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Epsilon','Zeta','Eta','Theta'],  'Date': ['Jul-1995','1994','Mar-1996','Apr-1990','1996','Jun-1996','Jul-1997','Aug-1999']})`

Do I need to change the concatenate formula or the formatting of the Date column? Or do I need to change both? Or something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried & instead of concatenate() ? Also check the formatting of cells C2 or consider forcing the formatting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.